# How to add a bool value to a db in java

Tags: java, sql, string, jdbc, boolean

I have a string sending data to a database. I am getting an error by value.

I believe this is because the final row in my database is a bool value which is default 1 as in true.

I want this value to be set to false based on the entry 9 in to my databse which is called relationship. For example

if Relationship is Business 
the bool value should be set to 0 
else 
bool value 1

I am confused on how to do this and get this string entered correctly. Here is my current method.

```
 private void Cmd_saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        try {
          String sql ="Insert Into contact (id, Business_Name, First_Name, Last_Name, Phone, Email, Address_Line_1, Address_Line_2, Website, Relationship, Answer) value (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
          pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

          pst.setString(1,tb0.getText());
          pst.setString(2,tb1.getText());
          pst.setString(3,tb2.getText());
          pst.setString(4,tb3.getText());
          pst.setString(5,tb4.getText());
          pst.setString(6,tb5.getText());
          pst.setString(7,tb6.getText());
          pst.setString(8,tb7.getText());
          pst.setString(9,tb8.getText());
          pst.setString(10,tb9.getSelectedItem().toString());
          pst.setString(11.toString();

          rs = pst.executeQuery();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);  
        } 
    }
```

Comment: what's pst.setString(11.toString()? Have you tried setBoolean method?

Comment: I rolled the modification back. Don't update the question in response to solutions in answers. It is confusing for people coming to the question later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`PreparedStatement.setBoolean(int parameterIndex, boolean x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBoolean%28int,%20boolean%29) method. For example:

```
pst.setBoolean(11, tb9.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Business"));
```

Note that it is *not* a query that is being executed (it is an `INSERT`), so this is incorrect:

```
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

instead:

```
pst.executeUpdate(); // In this case you are expecting a return value of 1,
                     // which you should check to ensure the insert happened.
```

And it is `VALUES`, not `value`, in the `INSERT` statement (case is unimportant, I just prefer uppercase for keywords when writing SQL).

Comment: 11 is the bool object. So your saying just swap line 11 with your line of code? and How would I go about changing this value based on the relationship added on line 10? its a combo box with 4 values. If the value Relationship is picked I need the bool to be set to true instead of false. otherwise I need it set to false.

Comment: also sqlite does not have boolean it only has bool does this matter? if I setBoolean?

Comment: @NichoDiaz, updated answer with what I think you mean and I have not used sqlite but I would be surprised if `setBoolean()` did not work with a `bool` data type.

Comment: ok wow you're awesome. Please explain something to me.. So in the statement were setBoolean to the place in DB 11 then getting selected item from the combobox sending object toString that when it " WHen it equals Business? " this part confuses me the end?

Comment: hmm it says syntax error by value still... i updated my recent code.

Comment: I still get syntax error. Is this because I dont need to add a ? for values being entered for the bool?

Comment: @NichoDiaz, the `?` is required for each parameter. Updated answer again due to `value` instead of `VALUES` in the `INSERT` statement text.